# Iterator in template c++

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I am trying to understand templates. I am trying to navigate through elements, but I don't know how to get iterator of type T.

```
template <typename T, typename _Comparator = less<typename T::value_type>>
class MyClass{
  public:
///...
   typename T <typename T::value_type>::iterator i; // not working
///...
}


int main(){
  MyClass <list<string>> a1;
  MyClass <list<string>, CStrComparator> a2 ( list<string>{ "Hello", "world", "test", "this", "foo", "TEsT", "this", "done" }, CStrComparator ( false ) ); 
}
```

error:

```
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/stl2/main.cpp||In member function ‘std::set<int> MyClass<_Type, _Comparator>::Search(const T&) const’:|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/stl2/main.cpp|27|error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘T’|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/stl2/main.cpp|27|error: expected ‘(’ before ‘T’|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/stl2/main.cpp|27|error: expected ‘;’ before ‘T’|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/stl2/main.cpp||In function ‘int main()’:|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/stl2/main.cpp|179|error: template argument 1 is invalid|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/stl2/main.cpp|179|error: template argument 2 is invalid|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/stl2/main.cpp|180|error: ‘t6’ was not declared in this scope|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/stl2/main.cpp||In constructor ‘MyClass<std::basic_string<char>, _Comparator>::MyClass(const string&, const _Comparator&) [with _Comparator = std::less<char>, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’:|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/stl2/main.cpp:118|34|instantiated from here|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/stl2/main.cpp|75|warning: ‘MyClass<std::basic_string<char> >::sequence’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/stl2/main.cpp|74|warning:   ‘std::less<char> MyClass<std::basic_string<char> >::cmp’ [-Wreorder]|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/stl2/main.cpp|40|warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]|
||=== Build finished: 6 errors, 3 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Please avoid (leading/trailing) underscores (See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: sry _Type was T ... i copied old code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already use the "type of elements of the container T"

```
typename T::value_type
```

The same is for iterators:

```
typename T::iterator i;
```

Comment: wow it works. So I dont have to specify value_type of elements in T for iterator ?

Comment: T is a placeholder for the valuetype.  This is what makes templates useful.

Comment: `T` is `list<string>` in the original example, so `T::iterator` is `list<string>::iterator`.